# Need help with transformation formula: how to get the pdf of $T$ given you know the pdf of $\ln(T)$

Tags: probability, density-function

I know the answer is:

$$f_T(t) = \frac{d}{dt} F_{\ln t}(\ln(t)) = f_{\ln t}(\ln t) \frac{1}{t}$$

which you can get by using cdfs and taking the derivative.

$$F_T(t) = P(T \le t) = P(\ln(T) \le \ln(t)) = F_{\ln t}(\ln(t))$$

---

**My question:** I am having difficulty getting the answer using this alternative approach which uses the formula:

$$f_Y(y) = f_X(x) \frac{dx}{dy} \quad \text{with} \quad x = g^{-1}(y)$$

**My attempt:**

Here $Y = T$ and $X = \ln T$ so we have

$$f_T(t) = f_{\ln T}(x) \frac{dx}{dt} $$

and now I have to find $x = g^{-1}(t)$ but at this point I'm stuck. I know $x = lnt$ but I'm having issues writing this out formally.

It's tripping me out because we go from $lnt$ to $t$ which is a simpler function. Thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: $dt=tdx = e^xdx$

Comment: the pdf is defined such that $f(x)dx$ gives the probability that $x$ will be measured in between $x$ and $x+dx$

Comment: @phdmba7of12 thanks for your help... hmm it seems $t=e^x$? How do you get to the conclusion that $x=g^{-1}(t) = lnt$? Thanks again!

Comment: $e^{\ln z}=z$ just exponentiate both sides of the $x = \ln t$ equation

Comment: one way might be to use delta function as kernel for the transform: $$F(x)=\int_0^x f(x)dx$$ and $$F(\ln t)=\int_0^{\ln t}f(\ln t)d\left(\ln t \right)$$

Comment: @phdmba7of12 thanks for your help... sorry I'm kind of slow. I know it's a bit pedantic but can you write out the logical steps and I'd love to give you karma for doing the lord's work